# Populate datatable from textarea input

Tags: aura, lightning-datatable, lightning-textarea

I have two textarea inputs taking in columns and data for the datatable(format seen in default values below).

```
    <aura:attribute name="values" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="columns" type="String"/>
                        <lightning:textarea name="datatablecolumninput" label="Input Columns"
                        value="[
                        { label: 'Opportunity name', fieldName: 'opportunityName', type: 'text'},
                        {
                            label: 'Confidence',
                            fieldName: 'confidence',
                            type: 'percent',
                            cellAttributes: { iconName: { fieldName: 'trendIcon' },
                            iconPosition: 'right' }
                        },
                        {
                            label: 'Amount',
                            fieldName: 'amount',
                            type: 'currency',
                            typeAttributes: { currencyCode: 'EUR'}
                        },
                        { label: 'Contact Email', fieldName: 'contact', type: 'email'},
                        { label: 'Contact Phone', fieldName: 'phone', type: 'phone'}
                    ]"
                        onchange="{!c.handleDatatableColumns}" />
                    <lightning:textarea name="datatablevalueinput" label="Input Values"
                        value="[{
                            id: 'a',
                            opportunityName: 'Cloudhub',
                            confidence: 0.2,
                            amount: 25000,
                            contact: 'jrogers@cloudhub.com',
                            phone: '2352235235',
                            trendIcon: 'utility:down'
                        },
                        {
                            id: 'b',
                            opportunityName: 'Quip',
                            confidence: 0.78,
                            amount: 740000,
                            contact: 'quipy@quip.com',
                            phone: '2352235235',
                            trendIcon: 'utility:up'
                    }]"
                        onchange="{!c.handleDatatableValues}" />
```

On change, I am setting the two attributes

```
({handleDatatableColumns: function (component, event, helper) {

        component.set("v.columns",event.getParam("value"));

    },

    handleDatatableValues: function (component, event, helper) {

        component.set("v.values",event.getParam("value"));


    },
})
```

I am then trying to populate the datatable but nothing is displaying

```
  <lightning:datatable
                keyField="id"
                data="{!v.values}"
                columns="{!v.columns}"
                hideCheckboxColumn="true"/>
```

How do I change the input from textarea into a format that can be populated in the datatable?

EDIT: Changing the input to Json format and then parsing it works, but the input specifically is going to be in object format. Is there a way to keep the input as it is and display the datatable?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to parse the string to convert it into the array object.

`component.set("v.columns",JSON.parse(event.getParam("value")));`

However, your attributes **datatablecolumninput** and **datatablevalueinput** are not valid JSON strings. Please put **"** around the key and values.

Comment: I was using Json stringify and parse both, hoping it would work. Changing it according to your answer works, but the input is supposed to be a javascript object and not in json format. Anyway, I am going with JSON format for now, till I find the answer to it.

Comment: Javascript object would be a JSON indeed. Hope I'm not missing anything here.